# Finding the minimum of two columns from two different rows in a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I am working on a SQL View which returns difference of two columns and minimum value of two columns that belongs to two different rows of single table.

I was able to find the difference but was not able to return the minimum value of two columns

I have the following table

```
 id      Market  Grade       Term    BidVolume   Bid     Offer   OfferVolume
    1       Heavy   ABC         Jun14 1000     -19.5      -17         2500
    2       Heavy   ABC         Jul14 2000      -20      -17.5        1400 
    3       Sour    XYZ         Jun14 3000      -30       -17         2300  
    4       Sour    XYZ         Jul14 1500      -32       -27         2900
```

And I have the following SQL query and its results below

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[InferredBids] AS
WITH numbered AS
  ( SELECT id, product, grade, term, bid, offer, termid, bidVolume, offerVolume,
           row_number() OVER (Partition BY Product, Grade ORDER BY termid) i
   FROM dbo.CanadianCrudes) --select * from numbered
SELECT r1.id AS Id,
       r1.product + '/' + r1.grade AS Market,
       r1.term + '/' + r2.term AS Term,
       r1.Bid - r2.Offer [Bid], r1.Offer - r2.Bid [Offer]
FROM numbered r1
JOIN numbered r2 ON r1.product = r2.product
AND r1.grade = r2.grade
AND r1.termid+1=r2.termid
AND r1.i<r2.i
AND r1.term!=r2.term
```

And Results are as follows fro the above query

```
Market     Term          Bid                   Offer
Heavy/ABC  Jun14/Jul14   (-19.5-(-17.5))=-2    (-17-(-20))=3
Sour/XYZ  Jun14/Jul14    (-30-(-27))=-3        (-17-(-32))=15
```

But I am trying to include another 2 columns called BidVolume and OfferVolume and results should be something like following

```
Market     Term          BidVolume                  Bid                   Offer        OfferVolume     
 Heavy/ABC  Jun14/Jul14  Min(1000,1400)=1000    (-19.5-(-17.5))=-2     (-17-(-20))=3  Min(2500,2000)=2000
 Sour/XYZ  Jun14/Jul14    Min(3000,2900)=2900   (-30-(-27))=-3        (-17-(-32))=15   Min(2300,1500)=1500
```

What would be the best way to include them

Comment: You can get the lesser of two values with something like `CASE WHEN m < n THEN m ELSE n END`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aggregate functions, such as `MIN` are for aggregating across multiple rows, and will not do what you expect here (as you've already found out). Instead, you should use a `case` to choose which table and column to show from. *Yes, I mean "table" here because your two joined rows are coming from separate logical tables, aliased `t1` and `t2`.*

For example, for `BidVolume`:

```
case when r1.BidVolume < r2.OfferVolume then r1.BidVolume else r2.OfferVolume end
```

Comment: Please note that I am comparing two different columns in the table BidVolume and OfferVolume. Your answer compares same columns but different rows

Comment: @Dev . . . This is comparing different columns in the same row.

Comment: Yes I saw that and fixed it with an edit. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @lc. your answer seems logical but it is not returning the correct results always. not sure why?

Comment: I'm not sure why either. I can't test it because your query refers to more columns than are in your example data, but I'm pretty sure this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @lc Can you take a look at this link sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0986/4/0  The second results looks as it should but the first one should be 31 instead of 2000. you know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Sorry -I misread the problem.

The real answer is that the first answer you received was close. The problem is its only comparing 2 of the 4 values.

In your SQL, you are always comparing 2 columns across 2 records - and you need the minimum of 4 different values, so in mysql, you would do this:

```
least( r1.bidVolume, r1.offerVolume, r2.bidVolume, r2.offerVolume) as Minimum_Volume
```

here's my original answer for posterity
To get the aggregate minimum from two different columns, you need 
a) expression that obtains the minimum value from the two columns for a given row
b) aggregate minimum of the above expression across all rows

For a), I will use mysql "IF" syntax, and you can adjust to the sql of your choice. The following query will select the minimum between the Bid and Offer volumes from the first table you posted on a per Market and per Grade basis:

```
select Market, Grade, min( if( BidVolume < OfferVolume, BidVolume, OfferVolume)) MinVol
from YourTable
group by Market, Grade
;
```

If you use the above as a template, you can adjust as needed for other business rules.

The results of the above would be:

```
Market  Grade       MinVol   
Heavy   ABC         1000
Sour    XYZ         1500
```

Comment: I am trying to find minimum of two different columns and two different rows.

Comment: that's what the sql i posted does, please see my edits